# Laravel read and write connection with sticky Option is not working after creation row

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 7.10.3 and PostgreSQL 12.
I have 2 connection with db (read/write). 
Also i set sticky option as true. 
This example has no sense, but it shows this problem:

```
$quest = factory(Quest::class)->create();
//if i remove comment for next lines, everything work alright. Because update was made. But when we make only create, select works via "read" connection.
//$quest->limit_winners = random_int(1, 200);
//$quest->update();
$quest = Quest::query()->where('id', $quest->id)->first();
print_r($quest);
```

Can anybody explain why after creating Laravel use read connection instead write?

Comment: How do you set the connection for the model?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I have not setting for connection in my models (i mean $connection property). My connection was set only in database.php configuration file.

Comment: What happens when you change `factory(Quest::class)->create();` to `Quest::create();`?

Comment: @DelenaMalan
i can change this to:
$quest = Quest::create(factory(Quest::class)->make()->toArray());
I think this is not a problem (i only use factory for creating some fake data for creating new row)

Comment: Cool. Does it work then or does the query then still read from the wrong connection?

Comment: The problem was not fixed. Now i am trying to research problem in Laravel Model and Builder classes.

Comment: I think i found issue with Laravel. I have added new pull request to repository of Laravel. I hope i understood correct this problem and this will be fixed.

Comment: @Nesh Please post the resolution that you found here.

Comment: @MarkusMulholland
It was an issue with laravel framework. I made fix in repository.
Here is details https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32966